# Redirecting twice to a website

Tags: php, css, screen-scraping, output

I am building a dictionary in a website. I call the original site's (www.rae.es) definitions of the terms and change their css for one of my own. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $word = $_REQUEST['word'];


    $url = "http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val={$word}";

    $css = <<<EOT

    <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
                font-family: 'brannboll_fetregular';
                src: url('brannbollfet-webfont.eot');
                src: url('brannbollfet-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                    url('brannbollfet-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
                    url('brannbollfet-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
                    url('brannbollfet-webfont.svg#brannboll_fetregular') format('svg');

                }

    .a
       {
        color: #ffe200;
        margin-top:20px !important;
       }
    .f
       {
         margin-left:20px !important;
         margin-top:10px;
         font-size: 200%;
         color: #ffe200;
         font-family: 'brannboll_fetregular';

       }
    .o
       {
         font-size: 80%;
         color: #ffe200;
         margin-left:10px;
         font-family: 'Belgrano', serif;
        }
    .q {
        margin-left:10px;
        font-family: 'Belgrano', serif;
        }
    .k {
        margin-left:10px;
        font-family: 'Belgrano', serif;
        }
    .p {

        font-family: 'Belgrano', serif;
        }     
    img
        {
        visibility:hidden;
         }

    </style>
    EOT;

    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = str_replace('<head>', $css.'</head>', $data);
    $data = str_replace('<span class="f"><b>.</b></span>', '', $data);
    echo '<div id="result1"
      style="
      top: 77%;
      left: 55%;
      overflow:scroll; 
      width:400px; 
      height:300px;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      border-radius: 15px;
      background-opacity: 0.5;
      background: #047C8F;
      -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
      -moz-border-radius: 15px;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 13px #000000;
      -moz-box-shadow:
                   0px 3px 13px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
                   inset 0px 0px 13px rgba(0,0,0,1);
      -webkit-box-shadow:
                   0px 3px 13px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
                   inset 0px 0px 13px rgba(0,0,0,1);
     ">
     '.$data.' 
     </div>';
        ?>
```

Now, sometimes, for some words, suggestions come up. For example: http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=casa . If you search "casa", you will come up with3 suggestions. Now, if IN MY SITE, I click on those hyperlinks, I am redirected to an error page. So, I now that the solution is in the hands of php, I just don't know where to start from.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the HTML you get from http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=casa, you will see that your suggestions links are relative links:

> <a href="search?id=wHzIYMmRVDXX2tX1bpuy">

Before sending them to the user you should change them into absolute links. You could do something like this:

> <?php $data = preg_replace('/(search?[\d\w]+)/','http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/\1', $data)

A better solution would be to use a DOMParser to parse the response from the server and use CSS selectors or xpath to find the links and rewrite their href attribute. Have a look at the [DOMCrawler Symfony component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html)

Answer (score 0):

The link points to a file that obviously does not exist on your server. You can either write something that handles the request to the file (e.g. using a mod_rewrite rewrite or a nginx "location"), or you scan the returned HTML code for these links and fix them before sending the HTML to the user.

Are you sure what you are doing is legal? It looks like you are copying the content of another website and passing it off as your own. Unless the website explicitly allows it, you are absolutely **not** supposed to do that.

Comment: 1) how can i "fix" the scanned links. 2) its legal as long as i dont make profits

Comment: Find them and replace them with links that point to one of your scripts (which then should show the correct answer)